# XP through the ages

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, experience-points

I'm looking for the definitions and basic usage of experience points in all the versions of D&D. Of particular interest is the stated purpose of having xp (and levels) in the game at all, if it's present.

Comment: similar question, but looking at HP: [How do interpretations of Hit Points vary among D&D editions?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108454)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definition of experience points and level from the original D&D set:

> In D&D rules, player characters try to gain experience, which is earned 
>   as **experience points** (or **XP**). Experience points are given out by
>   the DM at the end of each adventure. Player characters continue to gain
>   experience points for each adventure they participate in. Although this
>   rule book only explains the abilities of characters up to the third 
>   level of experience, further supplements will explain character levels
>   up to 36th level.
>
> **Use of the Word “Level”**
>
> EXPERIENCE: The word “level” has several different meanings in D&D
>   Adventure Game. A “level of experience” is a general term meaning an 
>   amount of experience points. When a character earns a given amount of
>   experience points (XP), that character gains one level of experience.
>   **All player characters begin the game at the first level of 
>   experience**, and will gain levels of experience through adventures.

The first edition AD&D books don’t seem to have quite so clear a definition but the 2nd Edition Player’s Handbook has this:

> **Experience Points** measure what a character has learned and how he 
>   has improved his skill during the course of his adventures. Characters
>   earn experience points by completing adventures and by doing things 
>   specifically related to their class. A fighter, for example, earns more
>   experience for charging and battling a monster than does a thief, 
>   because the figher’s training emphasises battle while the thief’s 
>   emphasises stealth and cleverness. Characters accumulate experience from
>   adventure to adventure. When they accumulate enough, they rise to the 
>   next level of experience, gaining additional abilities and powers. The
>   experience level tables for each character group list the *total*,
>   accumulated experience points needed to reach each level.
>
> **Level** is a measure of the character’s power. A beginning character 
>   starts at 1st level. To advance to the next level, the character must
>   earn a requisite number of experience points. Different character 
>   classes improve at different rates. Each increase in level improves the
>   character’s survivabilty and skills.

Comment: Great start! What about later editions?